# Blogspot website not opening on Browser

Tags: firefox, chromium, dns

My machine has a 64 bit Ubuntu installed on it. I am trying to access this website from my browser (Chromium as well as Firefox):

http://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2014/01/land-cover-classification-of-cropland.html

which is a Blogspot website.

Certain websites on a google search suggest modifying the DNS settings for 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 specially for browsing Blogspot websites. I did that, and restarted the computer as well connected to the internet.

However, the above website shows a DNS error and I am not able to browse it.

What could be causing this error?

Output of `nslookup fromgistors.blogspot.com` on my machine:

```
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
fromgistors.blogspot.com    canonical name = blogspot.l.googleusercontent.com.
Name:   blogspot.l.googleusercontent.com
Address: 173.194.36.11
Name:   blogspot.l.googleusercontent.com
Address: 173.194.36.10
Name:   blogspot.l.googleusercontent.com
Address: 173.194.36.12
```

Further, output of `nslookup fromgistors.blogspot.com 8.8.8.8` on my machine:

```
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
fromgistors.blogspot.com    canonical name = blogspot.l.googleusercontent.com.
Name:   blogspot.l.googleusercontent.com
Address: 74.125.236.108
Name:   blogspot.l.googleusercontent.com
Address: 74.125.236.107
Name:   blogspot.l.googleusercontent.com
Address: 74.125.236.106
```

Comment: What's the output of `nsloookup fromgistors.blogspot.com` and `nsloookup fromgistors.blogspot.com 8.8.8.8`? `nslookup` is available in the package `dnsutils`.

Comment: Added details on the lookup.

Comment: Thanks. The results look good with both the default and Google's DNS service. Now we need to find out, why your browsers don't get the same results. What are the network settings for Firefox and Chromium (which uses the system settings)? Are they configured to use a non-default DNS server? Do you experience the same issues in safe mode without any browser plug-ins or add-ons that might fudge with the network requests?

Comment: The site does not open on both browsers.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, we should enable asynchronous DNS. One should go to Chrome flags, by typing `chrome://flags` in the address bar and then `#enable-async-dns`.

On my machine this shows:

```
Client DNS asynchrone intégré Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS
Cette fonctionnalité active le client DNS asynchrone intégré et expérimental. #enable-async-dns
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other OS running on your system? Did you try opening the website on that?
Moreover, I don't have DNS set up as 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and have accessed all the blogspot websites that have come in my way. So, I think you'd be good without that too.

Anyway, what DNS error are you getting exactly? 
It could be because you're blocked to access such a website(From ISP or from the owner of the blog.)
I can't really give you much insight into the solution until I know the problem well. A screenshot, or the DNS error code would have helped.

Still, I guess, there's one way you might be able to access your page. Here, try this trick :

1. Go to Google
2. Paste the whole URL there and click Search
3. Instead of opening the page, open the cached version of the page. Click on the arrow beneath the page headline at the right of the whole link in green, click on it, and you'll see two options - Cached, and Similar. Click on Cached. You'll be able to see the whole page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Impossible de trouver le serveur de fromgistors.blogspot.com, car la résolution DNS a échoué. DNS est le service Web qui convertit les noms de sites Web en adresses Internet. Cette erreur est généralement due à l'absence de connexion Internet ou à une configuration incorrecte du réseau. Elle peut également être causée par un serveur DNS qui ne répond pas ou par un pare-feu qui interdit l'accès de Chromium au réseau.
Code d'erreur : DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.